# ASP.NET Css will not work

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Im trying too get CSS too work on my page but I can't fix this. Can some one take a look at my code and help me?

This is the place where I want my css.
Css pagename is StyleSheet.css

```
@model IEnumerable<DNDB.Models.Domeinnaam>

<head> @Styles.Render("~/Content/StyleSheet.css") </head>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Domeinnaam Overzicht</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Voeg toe", "Create")
</p>
<table class="tabledomeinnamen">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IsActief) 
    </th>
```

This is my _layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@Styles.Render("~/Content/StyleSheet.css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

StyleSheet.css

```
#body {
width: 100%;
background-color: red;
} 

#tabledomeinnamen {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 60%;
color: white;   
background-color: red;
}


#tabledomeinnamen td {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: forestgreen;
}
#Banner {
width: 75%;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;

}

#Footer {
width       :75%;
margin      :0 auto;
color       :black;
clear       :both;
text-align  :center;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 25px;
}
#menu {
text-align: center;
}
```

Can some one tell me or explain me how I should fix this?

EDIT: I'm kinda new to programming so this isn't easy for me.

Comment: You should show your output, do you have any errors?

Comment: i don't. It just won't work. The css that is on my layout page works. But for example I have 
#table td {
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        background-color: forestgreen; } And that part is on my other page. this won't work.

Comment: which version of asp.net MVC?

Comment: Strange location to declare your head section. Where is your body section?

Comment: 4.5.2 is my version

Comment: @yanickvanBarneveld Its just an automated page from db too list. I just need too add the css so with the <head> I just tried something

Comment: What will happen if you remove the <head> tags around the @Styles.Render?

Comment: @YanickvanBarneveld Nothing happens if I do this. no error, just nothing

Comment: How does your CSS looks like? You said you have #table td but you dont have a ID on the table, only a class named tabledomeinnamen.

Comment: You don't have to add the `@Style.Render` in your View if you use a shared `_layout`. All your cshml view files are load in the `body` section of your `layout`

Comment: Change <table class="tabledomeinnamen"> to <table id="tabledomeinnamen">

Comment: @Alexis The _layout css works. But like I said the #tabledomeinnamen td {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background-color: forestgreen;
} Will not work. The css for the _layout works perfectly

Comment: @onedevteam.com ty ! it worked <3

Comment: @onedevteam.com You know how I can make something like 1 row white, 1 grey 1 white 1 grey etc. I know there is a command or something for it but I don't know the name or the command

Comment: @Marijn are you having BundleConfig.cs file?

Comment: @Aravind its fixed already ;)

Comment: if u used any of these answers which are below. Mark them as answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS is wrong, you are using an ID selector instead of a class selector. The hash (#) means that you call to a ID within your HTML. But if you look at your HTML you only have a class defined on the table. To select elements with a specific class, write a period (.) character, followed by the name of the class in your CSS.

[More information about ID's and classes can be found here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)